# How to format numbers as thousands separators in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, format, numbers, dart-pub

I have to format numbers as thousands separators in dart. I have numbers like:

```
16987

13876

456786
```

and I want to format them as :

```
16,987

13,876 

4,56,786
```

Comment: you can try `NumberFormat` from `intl` package

Comment: My eyes are bleeding. Didn't you mean 456,786?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You can use NumberFormat passing a custom format in ICU formatting pattern, take a look in [NumberFormat](https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/NumberFormat-class.html).

```dart
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

void main() {
  var formatter = NumberFormat('#,##,000');
  print(formatter.format(16987));
  print(formatter.format(13876));
  print(formatter.format(456786));
}
```

Output

```
16,987
13,876
4,56,786
```

Comment: Is it possible to do the same for string? i am having hard time doing this.

Comment: @ManoHaran Hi! Use `double.tryParse("10000")` or `double.parse("10000")`, after this just format.

Comment: Hi! I wonder how I can apply this to display the number with '.' as separator. When I tried code above, it returns me an error --> Multiple decimal separators in pattern "Instance of 'StringIterator'". How can we tell the package that we are going to use different separator. I've tried using locale, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Hi @NaufalRajabi choose a different locale based on your need and try this example: `var formatter = NumberFormat('#,##,000', "ar_DZ");`

Reference => 
https://github.com/dart-lang/intl/blob/master/lib/number_symbols_data.dart

Answer (score 23):

I found [NumberFormat](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/NumberFormat-class.html) class from [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) package very useful as it provides different ways to format numbers.

By default the NumberFormat class format's number in million's using default American locale and we can format numbers in lakh using Indian locale(It can format number or currency according to any countries locale).`NumberFormat.decimalPattern([String locale])`.

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';   

void main() {
  NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.decimalPattern('hi');
  print(numberFormat.format(16987));
  print(numberFormat.format(13876));
  print(numberFormat.format(456786));
}
```

Output

```
16,987
13,876
4,56,786
```

Answer (score 6):

You don`t need to use NumberFormat package before you can do that. this should help, test it with any number.

```
String formatAmount(){
    String price = "1000000000";
    String priceInText = "";
    int counter = 0;
    for(int i = (price.length - 1);  i >= 0; i--){
        counter++;
        String str = price[i];
        if((counter % 3) != 0 && i !=0){
          priceInText = "$str$priceInText";
        }else if(i == 0 ){
          priceInText = "$str$priceInText";
        
        }else{
          priceInText = ",$str$priceInText";
        }
    }
    return priceInText.trim();
  }
```

Then you can use by printing:

```
print(formatAmount());
```

output:

```
 1,000,000,000
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want the comma separated value with decimals, use the `decimalPatternDigits` initializer and control the number of decimal places via the `decimalDigits` parameter.

Setting the `decimalDigits` parameter value to `0` will result in no decimals.

**With Decimals**

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.decimalPatternDigits(
    locale: 'en_us',
    decimalDigits: 2,
);

print(formatter.format(17459));
print(formatter.format(1000000));
print(formatter.format(100100.05));
print(formatter.format(100100.016));
```

output

```
17,459.00
1,000,000.00
100,100.05
100,100.02
```

**Without Decimals**

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.decimalPatternDigits(
    locale: 'en_us',
    decimalDigits: 0,
);

print(formatter.format(100100.05));
print(formatter.format(100100.999));
```

output

```
100,100
100,101
```

Answer (score 2):

Pseudocode for that activity would be around:

```
Here, `string` is an input string with indexes starting at 0.
let i = (length of string) - 3
while i > 0 do
    insert a "," into string at position (i)
    let i = i - 3
return string
```

DartCode

```
extension on int {
  String get priceString {
    final numberString = toString();
    final numberDigits = List.from(numberString.split(''));
    int index = numberDigits.length - 3;
    while (index > 0) {
      numberDigits.insert(index, ',');
      index -= 3;
    }
    return numberDigits.join();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this more flexible extension:

```
/// Return as number as formatted in thousands string.
/// Example: -123456.asThousands() returns -123'456
String asThousands({
  final String separator = "'",
  final int digits = 3,
}) {
  assert(digits >= 1, '5d40ef0f-f8b4-4070-adf4-bbfc1a8b663b');
  final chars =
      abs().truncate().toString().split(StringHelper.empty).reversed;
  var n = 0;
  var result = StringHelper.empty;
  for (final ch in chars) {
    if (n == digits) {
      result = '$ch$separator$result';
      n = 1;
    } else {
      result = '$ch$result';
      n++;
    }
  }
  result = this < 0 ? '-$result' : result;
  result = (this is double)
      ? '$result${toString().substring(toString().lastIndexOf('.'))}'
      : result;
  return result;
}
```

Sample calls:

```
test('Test NumHelper.asThousands()', () {
  expect(
    123456789.asThousands(separator: StringHelper.space),
    '123 456 789',
  );
  expect(123456789.asThousands(separator: ','), '123,456,789');
  expect(
    123456789.asThousands(separator: ',', digits: 2),
    '1,23,45,67,89',
  );
  expect((-123456789).asThousands(separator: ','), '-123,456,789');
  expect((-123456).asThousands(separator: ','), '-123,456');
  expect((-12345).asThousands(separator: ','), '-12,345');
  expect(1.asThousands(), '1');
  expect(12.asThousands(), '12');
  expect(123.asThousands(), '123');
  expect(1995.asThousands(), "1'995");
  expect(12345678.asThousands(), "12'345'678");
  expect((-123456789.123).asThousands(separator: ','), '-123,456,789.123');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Thats the Indian format for currency. Hence intl package lets you convert numbers to locale currency. Using the standard patterns. For Indian format you can use.

```dart
NumberFormat.currency(locale: 'en_IN', symbol: '₹ ').format(value);
```

Or you can create an extension like this.

```dart
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

extension Currency on double {
  String indianFormat() {
    return NumberFormat.currency(locale: 'en_IN', symbol: '₹ ').format(this);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily with `intl` package

```
var formatter = NumberFormat('###,000');

double number = 1234;
String output = NumberFormat.decimalPattern().format(number); // 1,234
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to format a number with the thousands separator and give it a max number of decimal numbers.

```
var formatter = NumberFormat('#,##0.' + "#" * 5); 

print(formatter.format(double.parse('1000.456781234'.replaceAll(",", ""))));

OUTPUT: 1,000.45678
```

Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way here is a use NumberFormat class from the `intl`, please follow the given steps for the same.

Add this package to your `pubspec.yaml`

```
dependencies:
  intl: ^0.17.0
```

Use this below line of code in your dart extension file

```
final numberFormat = NumberFormat.decimalPattern('hi');

extension ExtOnNum on num {
  format() {
    final parts = toString().split('.');
    return '${numberFormat.format(num.tryParse(parts[0]) ?? 0.0)}.${parts[1]}';
  }
}
```

Output:

```
print(5843.41.format());

5,843.41
```

Answer (score 0):

For thousand seperator

> stringAmount.replaceAllMapped(RegExp(r'(\d{1,3})(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))'),
> (Match m) => "${m[1]}.");

'2352' ---> '2.352'

'3452' ---> '23.452'

'235223' ---> '235.223'

. is for Türkiye to use , seeperator change . to , from end of code