# how to take a hundred thousand from million in dart

Tags: dart

I want to separate thousand hundreds from millions? Is there any way to do that?

**for example:**

```
int 7770493;

result1 = 7000000;
result2 = 770493;
```

Comment: Check answers here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62580280/how-to-format-numbers-as-thousands-separators-in-dart

Comment: Look at the `~/` and `%` operators or `modulo` method on `int`.